# Maven : generate only report

Tags: maven, cobertura, pmd, surefire

i have this POM.xml

```
<reporting>
<plugins>
   <plugin>  
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>  
    <version>3.0.1</version>  
    <reportSets>
      <reportSet>
        <reports>
          <report>pmd</report>
          <report>cpd</report>
        </reports>
      </reportSet>
    </reportSets>
 </plugin>

 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
  </plugin>

   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.14</version>
  </plugin>

</plugins>
```

when I use `mvn site` ,it generate for me a fuuly website but what i want is to generate only reports.

who can help me by providing a command that do this job?

Comment: Please come with more details